# Open and free electronic Case Report Form e-CRF system options

Tags: medical

Does anyone know any good platform for gathering clinical data during clinical trials?

I was not able to set up Open Clinica...

I think that this problem should be addressed more easily with a form for data acquisition.

I am looking for a simple solution not a mySQL database and involvement of the whole IT department.

Google Forms were ok but they lack conditional logic.

Any other options?

Comment: you want conditional logic, but not a database.....confusing. when you say platform for gathering, do you mean somewhere to host the data?

Comment: I basically want google forms with conditional logic